# Regex matching original datetime format in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I've crafted a regex to find unique datetime formats. I want to substitute out invalid datetimes (where the month is not 1 through 12).

i.e.

```
10-2019  (NO MATCH)
2-2020 (NO MATCH)
19-2019 (MATCH because 2-digit is not 1-12)
```

I do not care about the 4-digit number. Thus, I've derived this regex:
`\b(0|00|1[3-9]|[2-9][0-9])\b-\d{4}`

However, I'm not receiving any matches:

```py
>>> x = '00-1421 a 15-1432'
>>> re.sub('\b(0|00|1[3-9]|[2-9][0-9])\b-\d{4}','',x)
'00-1421 a 15-1432'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = re.compile(r'\b(0|00|1[3-9]|[2-9]\d)-\d{4}')
x = '00-1421 a 15-1432'
p.sub('', x)
```

output:

```
' a '
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the `\d` at the end of the 2 digit block. Thanks!